# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ boundaryless?

Tags: general-topology

I just have a quick question, as stated in the title.

Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ boundary-less?

Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: Isn't each topological space boundary-less?

Comment: That is good to know, thanks Stefan H.... But you mean the whole set, not topological subset, right? As @Shaun Ault answered below, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is boundaryless if it sits in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but is with boundary it it sits in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: That's why you should always specify the underlying space. $A$ may have a boundary in $X$, but $A$ regarded as a subset of the space $(A,\tau)$ (where $\tau$ can be any topology, but mostly one takes the subspace topology) has no boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on whether you consider $\mathbb{R}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \geq 3$.  In the former case, there are no points in the boundary; in the latter, $\partial \mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Fairly clear, thank you very much!!

Comment: This question arises from the settlement: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417789/a-direct-application-of-sards-theorem. So to my understanding, it is boundaryless under this scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Ah... boundary can mean something different in manifolds.  $\mathbb{R}^2$ is boundaryless as a manifold, because all points can be surrounded by an open 2-disk.

Comment: For $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ in the transversality theorem - it is still boundaryless right? (Suppose that $F: X \times S \rightarrow Y$ is a smooth map of manifolds, where only $X$ has boundary, and let $Z$ be any boundaryless submanifold of $Y$. If both $F$ and $\partial F$ are transversal to $Z$, then for almost every $s \in S$, both $f_s$ and $\partial f_s$ are transeversal to $Z$.)

Comment: For the purposes of this theorem, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a manifold without boundary.  The following link may help, though you should also consult a text in which manifolds with and without boundary are defined precisely.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$\partial A= \overline{A}\setminus  \overset{\circ}{A}$$
so what's the adherence and the interior of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. Could you please inform me that what do you mean by $\overset{\circ}{A}$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, by adherence, do you mean closure? Thanks.

Comment: @MathSnail The circle above a topological space denotes the interior. And I believe you are correct that adherence means closure in this context.

Comment: Yes the adherence is the closure.

Comment: Hi @SamiBenRomdhane, Thanks very much for your guidance. So the adherence of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the interior of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is also $\mathbb{R}^2$. So $\mathbb{R}^2$ is boundaryless.

Comment: Yes this is the right answer.