# A direct application of Sard's theorem

Tags: differential-topology

The question is let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, show that for almost every $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $f^{-1}(\{c\}\times\mathbb{R})$ is a smooth submanifold of $X$.

I want to apply Sard's theorem. But the precise statement I plan to use is:

For any smooth map $f$ of a manifold $X$ with boundary into a boundaryless manifold $Y$, almost every point of $Y$ is regular value of both $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $\partial f: \partial X \rightarrow Y$.

To my understanding, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is boundaryless under this situation according to 
Shaun Ault's respons at
[Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ boundaryless?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417774/is-mathbbr2-boundaryless/417785?noredirect=1#417785)

But the bigger problem is, I don't know if $X$ is with boundary. I hope the condition that $X$ is with boundary is to apply the later part of the theorem, $\partial f: \partial X \rightarrow Y$. So when we only need almost every point of $Y$ is regular value of $f: X \rightarrow Y$, we don't need to know if $X$ is with boundary.

This sounds make sense, but I really don't want to assume anything when I am starting to learn differential topology. So could anyone point me some directions?

Thank you very much

Comment: It sounds like that formulation of Sard's theorem isn't the best tool for this problem.  Do you know any other formulations which might help?

Comment: Thanks Adam. This is the closest I have, others involve measure zero.

Comment: Just checking -- do you know the relationship between "measure zero" and "almost every"?

Comment: Not really - they are the same....?

Comment: You should definitely look this up before returning to Sard's theorem!  Briefly: the sentence "almost every $x \in X$ has property $P$" is equivalent to "the set of $x \in X$ *without* property $P$ has measure zero."  If you are working from a textbook or a set of notes, this should be addressed.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you so much for your clarification. Yes, that is what I understood. Thanks so much for your guidance.